# How to browse a result of a query and write lines (skipping repeats)?

Tags: python, sql

I'm a beginner in python, and I don't know how to do this.

I want to count the data returned, and if they are the same then I write them only once.

Here's my python's code:

```py
sl_lib = 'select distinct lib,name from place order by lib,name'
res = db.query(sl_lib)

for lig in res :
    rayVar = lig['lib']
    raySVar = lig['name']
print raySVar + rayVar
```

My result:

```
item1 + test1

item1 + test2

item1 + test3

item2 + glo1

item2 + glo2

item3 + htlo1
```

What I expect:

```
item1 + test1

test2

test3

item2 + glo1

glo 2

item3 + htlo1
```

**Note: there is a lot of data.**

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Nope its more advanced.

Comment: To confirm: you want to only print the first column (raySVar) if it is new, but always print the second column (rayVar)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only looking to print the first column when it's new, you can add some logic into your code to compare the current value to the previous.

```
sl_lib = 'select distinct lib,name from place order by lib,name'
res = db.query(sl_lib)

#initialize empty first col
name = ''

for lig in res :
     lib = lig['lib'] #always capture second column

    #check for new first column
    if lib['name'] != name:
        name = lig['name']
        print name + lib

    #if not new, just print 2nd col
    else:
        print lib
```

Comment: Yeah its something like that. I edited your post. It missing something when you go on the for.

`for lig in res :
# name is always ' ' and it should be the previous name`